# function call and execution in R

Tags: r, function, call, sequential

I have 2 functions defined one after the other. When I call them as a block the 1st function is executed (will become clear when you see below and I understand whats happening here and why it's happening) and the second function call gets ignored. Can this be fixed ?

Apologies if this is a repeat question. Can't seem to find the solution for this.

```
mini_val<-function()
{
  m <- readline("Minimum: ")
  if(!grepl("^[0-9]+$",m))
  {
    return(mini_val())
  }
  return(as.integer(m))
}

mini<-mini_val()

max_val<-function()
{
  m <- readline("Maximum: ")
  ifelse(!grepl("^[0-9]+$",m),return(max_val()),ifelse(m>=mini,as.integer(m),return(max_val()))) 
  return(as.integer(m))
}

maxi<-max_val()
```

when I run the entire block, the following happens:

```
 mini<-mini_val()
Minimum number of segments (between 3 and 20) or Hit ESC to exit:   
Minimum number of segments (between 3 and 20) or Hit ESC to exit:   max_val<-function()
Minimum number of segments (between 3 and 20) or Hit ESC to exit:   {
Minimum number of segments (between 3 and 20) or Hit ESC to exit:     m <- readline("Maximum number of segments (between 3 and 20) or Hit ESC to exit: ")
Minimum number of segments (between 3 and 20) or Hit ESC to exit:     ifelse(!grepl("^[0-9]+$",m),return(max_val()),ifelse(m>=mini,as.integer(m),return(max_val()))) 
Minimum number of segments (between 3 and 20) or Hit ESC to exit:     return(as.integer(m))
Minimum number of segments (between 3 and 20) or Hit ESC to exit:   }
Minimum number of segments (between 3 and 20) or Hit ESC to exit:   
Minimum number of segments (between 3 and 20) or Hit ESC to exit:   maxi<-max_val()
Minimum number of segments (between 3 and 20) or Hit ESC to exit: 1
>
```

Any idea how I can get around this ?

Thanks!, LR.

Comment: It would depend on what language this is written in.

Comment: Please add a language tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second function gets ignored because your program is still taking in `readline("Minimum: ")` input from the command line. You'll need to give it a numeric response first to proceed with your code.

For instance, you could just add a line with nothing but `4` after the `mini_val()` line, and it will work when you run them in a block:

```
...
}

mini<-mini_val()
4

max_val<-function()
{
...
```

Though this will not be very useful, since it's the same as running `mini <- 4`.

To produce the behavior you want, you need to run this in a .R file with `source("yourfile.R")`, rather than on the command line. (Presumably you were either copy-pasting it into R, or running it in RStudio by selecting all, or a similar procedure for running it line-by-line). When you source it from a file, you get the desired behavior:

```
> source("yourfile.R")
Minimum: 2
Maximum: 3
```

Comment: That's right, David. But this is part of a larger code wherein there are other things happening. This sections allows the user to input their chosen minimum and maximum value. So your solution doesn't exactly solve my issue. Calling only when I want to input does not fix the problem either. The functions will be called one after the other *immediately*.

Comment: @LavanyaRamanan See my edit; to get this behavior you'll need to source it from a file rather than running it in a block.

Comment: Thanks a tonne. That worked and solves my problem. I'm still curious if this can be fixed while running in command line (R or RStudio).

Comment: Why are you asking a user for input if they're running the program interactively in the command line? Any user who would run it in that way would presumably rather enter the values into the code, or call a function with that as parameters.

Comment: In case you are interested: enclosing the entire block within {} and then running it in command line fixes the issue. No idea why this works but it does. LR.

Comment: RE your previous comment: the user executing the code may not know all they need to about the code or where the numbers should be input in the code. Trying to create a block of code that can work as a black box. Hope that gives some context.